# Style.Triggers in TimeSpanEditBox actipro doesn't work as expected

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm using actipro version 22, I am trying to set the background color to green when mouseOver event occurs, but nothing happens.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TimeSpanEditBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type editors:TimeSpanEditBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <editors:TimeSpanEditBox Style="{StaticResource TimeSpanEditBoxStyle}"  Width="100" Height="35">
 </Grid>
```

Comment: This may happen when the ControlTemplate of the TimeSpanEditBox does not use the Background property (either not at all or not when IsMouseOver is true). We do not know how the default Style or ControlTemplate look like.

Comment: @Clemens Is it possible to overwrite it?